# How do i get the input value from moment object

Tags: angular, momentjs

I get a date back from the server and it has the correct time in the _i variable but the time is rounded to 00.00 in d variable - see below - how do I get the value in the _i variable??

```
      this.xxxxxStartDate = moment(
        data.xxxxxStartDate
      ).format("Do MMMM YYYY");

      this.xxxxxStartDateTime = moment(
        data.xxxxxStartDate
      ).format("HH:mm");

> _d: Wed Oct 20 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Irish Standard Time) {}
> _f: "YYYY-MM-DD"
> _i: "2021-10-20T09:11:00"
> _isAMomentObject: true
> _isUTC: false
> _isValid: true
> _locale: Locale {_calendar: {…}, _longDateFormat: {…}, _invalidDate: 'Invalid date', _dayOfMonthOrdinalParse: /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)/,
> ordinal: ƒ, …}
> _pf: {empty: false, unusedTokens: Array(0), unusedInput: Array(1), overflow: -1, charsLeftOver: 9, …}
```

Comment: Can you type an example value for `data.xxxxxStartDate`?

Comment: @alpakyol The response object is in the question - _d variable is returned but I want to show the value of _i , I want to show the time i.e. something like this: Wed Oct 20 2021 09:11:00 but instead I get 00:00

Comment: No, I'm asking the response data returned from server. Only `data.xxxxxStartDate`. The response you shared is an output about `moment()` call.

Comment: Thanks for your time @alpakyol I realised the format _f was not correct and wasn't updating the _d variable with the time so was sending the default 00:00 time back - the format has been updated and is working as expected now \(",)/ thanks again for taking the time to look at this

Answer (score 0):

Incase it might help someone with same issue.
The issue was in my service call i.e.
this.policyStartDate = moment(this.policyStartDate, "YYYY-MM-DD"),

This is why my moment object _f variable was ignoring the time

**_f: "YYYY-MM-DD"**

So when I changed the format in my service to:
this.policyStartDate = moment(this.policyStartDate, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"),
it worked as expected.

with _f looking like this:

**_f: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"**

An oversight on my part but might save someone else a bit of time. The question from @alpakyol helped me realise the issue, so thanks for that